# c# FileSystemWatcher trigger delete event when i create a new New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx file

Tags: c#, .net

C# FileSystemWatcher trigger delete event when i create new "New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx" file.

Step 1: I create new file "New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx"
Step 2: The FileSystemWatcher trigger Create event
Step 3: The FileSystemWatcher trigger Delete event

I don't want to have any delete events when I create an excel file.

This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var monitorSyncing = new MonitorSyncing(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MONITORING_FOLDER_PATH"]);
        monitorSyncing.Monitoring();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class MonitorSyncing
{
    public MonitorSyncing(string monitorPath)
    {
        this._monitorPath = monitorPath;
    }

    private readonly string _monitorPath;

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public void Monitoring()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"*** START MONITOR FOLDER: {this._monitorPath} ***");
        var fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings = new FileSystemSafeWatcher
        {
            Path = _monitorPath,
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Security,
            InternalBufferSize = 24576,
        };
        fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.Changed += OnChanged_SyncFolderUserSetting;
        fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.Created += OnChanged_SyncFolderUserSetting;
        fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.Deleted += OnChanged_SyncFolderUserSetting;
        fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.Renamed += OnRenamed_SyncFolderUserSetting;
        fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.Error += OnError;
        fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private static void OnChanged_SyncFolderUserSetting(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.ChangeType)
        {
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Created:
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}. Created file: {e.FullPath}");
                break;
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted:
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}. Deleted file: {e.FullPath}");
                break;
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Changed:
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}. Edit content file: {e.FullPath}");
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void OnRenamed_SyncFolderUserSetting(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        //  Show that a file has been renamed.
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}. Renamed file '{e.OldFullPath}' to '{e.FullPath}'");
    }


    private static void OnError(object source, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        //  Show that an error has been detected.
        Console.WriteLine($"Error - The FileSystemWatcher has detected an error : {e.GetException().Message}");
        //  Give more information if the error is due to an internal buffer overflow.
        if (e.GetException().GetType() == typeof(InternalBufferOverflowException))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(("Error - The file system watcher experienced an internal buffer overflow: " + e.GetException().Message));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want particular events - don't listen to such event... Or you are asking how your C# code can change behavior of unrelated application (i.e. Excel in your case)?

Comment: Hi Alex, I don't want to have delete event when I create new excel file